# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable (ImageOps.fit an image that calls cv2.cvtColor)

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm working with *`Keras`*, *`PIL.ImageGrab`*, *`cv2`* and *`tensorflow`* and there is an error that rises when I run my code(which is edited code from Teachable Machines stock code)

The error I get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Captey\Downloads\Stuff\Self_driving_cv2\Keras-Neural_net.py", line 23, in <module>
    image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

  File "Z:\Users\Captey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageOps.py", line 459, in fit
    bleed_pixels = (bleed * image.size[0], bleed * image.size[1])

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

My edited code:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Jul 10 23:31:44 2022

@author: Fahim Ferdous
Github: FahimFerdou1
Youtube: The_official_pyrite
    
"""
from keras.models import load_model
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageOps,Image
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

model = load_model('self_driving_model.h5')
data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)

while True:
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(285, 397,689, 812))
    img = np.array(img)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    size = (224, 224)
    image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    
    image_array = np.asarray(image)
    normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1
    data[0] = normalized_image_array
    
    prediction = model.predict(data)
    print(prediction)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
      break
    cv2.imshow('data',image)
```

Comment: you can't call PIL methods on numpy arrays.

Comment: What can I do to fix my code??

Comment: @FahimFerdous Convert `image` to `PIL` object; then pass it to `ImageOps.fit`

Comment: @JeruLuke Im sorry, im new to this which function would I need to call?

Comment: @FahimFerdous did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to `ImageOps.fit` convert your *numpy array* to *PIL object*:

```
image_PIL = Image.fromarray(image)
```

Now perform

```
size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image_PIL, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Proceed as usual.